# check if a number has its equivalent negative number in a list

Tags: python-3.x

need to traverse through a list and check if list members has its equivalent negative numbers also in same list 
Note: list will not have duplicates and considering performance as well

```
l = [2, -3, 1, 3, 5, 0, -5, -2]

d=defaultdict(list)
for num in l:
    if num>0:
        d['pos'].append(num)
    else:
        d['neg'].append(num)
print (d)
```

not sure how to proceed further. Could you help please

```
l = [2, -3, 1, 3, 5, 0, -5, -2]

output: [[2,-2],[-3,3],[5,-5]]
```

Comment: Should your output be True/False?

Comment: Can there be duplicates? If so, is each number 'consumed' exclusively?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please fix the indentation of your code in the question.

Comment: @N.Wouda - input list will not have duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there cannot be duplicates and you thus do not need to consider exclusive use of each number, you may use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), like so,

```
numbers = [2, -3, 1, 3, 5, 0, -5, -2]
unique_numbers = set(numbers)

paired = [[number, -number] for number in numbers
          if number > 0 and -number in unique_numbers]

print(paired)
```

For a result of `[[2, -2], [3, -3], [5, -5]]`.

Sets support `O(1)` membership checks. Constructing one from an existing list costs `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the list. Iterating over the list to compute the pairs is again `O(n)`, such that it runs in `O(n)` total, at the additional cost of some more memory for the set (again around `n`).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care  much about performance,

```
[[x, -x] for x in l if x > 0 and -x in l]
```